# Break-up year, months & days in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a input parameter dictionary as below -

```
InparamDict = {'DataInputDate':'2014-10-25'
              }
```

Using the field InparamDict['DataInputDate'], I want to pull up data from 2013-10-01 till 2013-10-25. What would be the best way to arrive at the same using Pandas?

The sql equivalent is -

```
DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,GETDATE())-1,DATEPART(month,GETDATE()),'01')
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mention if you're trying to pull up data from a DataFrame, Series or what. If you just want to get the date parts, you just have to get the attribute you want from the Timestamp object.

```
from pandas import Timestamp
dt = Timestamp(InparamDict['DataInputDate'])
dt.year, dt.month, dt.day
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are in a DataFrame (df) and you convert them to dates instead of strings. You can select the data by ranges as well, for instance

```
df[df['DataInputDate'] > datetime(2013,10,1)]
```